# Merging overlaid meshes

Tags: mesh, vertex-groups, 3d-printing, boolean-modifier

I am a novice to Blender and 3D-Printing. My Kids love Paw-Patrol and I found a bunch of pretty detailed models that I could print for my them. The issue is that the designer overlaid a bunch of meshes without merging them when creating the models. When I bring them into Cura to slice, this issue is revealed with holes and missing layers. The print doesn't know where to start and where to end. I tried to use CTRL L, create vertex groups, split them into individual objects, and use the bool tool to join everything, but it didn't work. How can this be accomplished? I can eliminate all the internal parts that don't matter to the 3D print, but that doesn't solve the overlap of all the groups found on the outside. Here is an example: https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/various/paw-patrol-rocky.

Thank you for all the help given here. I have really enjoyed learning Blender and working on these kinds of projects.

Comment: In the file you linked to, there is only a single mesh (the dog). If there are multiple meshes for you, have you tried using Ctrl-J to join them? Sorry if i'm missing anything, I don't 3d print.

Comment: He essentially took a bunch of different meshes, overlapped them, and made them a single STL mash. See the following link to download the blender file where I broke out all the overlapping meshes into vertex groups (they will still appear in blender as a single mesh but can be highlighted individually through such groups.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ulbxZnVlaJyv16H5ZE7T0SQa7k02n4V_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe the best way would be to separate out each vertex group into individual objects then one by one add them back on. Is there a good way to delete overlap other than the bool tool (union can be finicky sometimes)? Maybe that would accomplish what I am hoping to do. I tried using shrinkwrap. It was close, but not as precise as I would like.